# where to reference bootstrap in angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am writing an app in angular2, I wonder should we include bootstrap reference  on component level OR should we use in the index.html once.
What are the pros and cons of each style. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include the boostrap css within your index.html file.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If you want to use the [`ng2-bootstrap`](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap)  you can use it into your components this way:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Alert} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [Alert],
  template: `<alert type="info">ng2-bootstrap hello world!</alert>`
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

When you do it in the first way you have all the necessary styles needed for the elements, 2nd way has components that are available for angular2.